# QMessageBox: Failing to display text within the box (using c++)

Tags: c++, qmessagebox

have been stuck way to long with the simple(?) task to create a messagebox. The actual functionality works great, the buttons trigger the actions I want, but somehow the informative text in the box is invisible. Here's the code:

```
QMessageBox* msgBox;
    msgBox = new QMessageBox();
    msgBox->setWindowTitle("Open settings from file");
    msgBox->setText("Do you want to save your current settings to file first?");
    msgBox->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox->setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);      
    msgBox->exec();
```

Here's the result:

[MsgBox with invisible text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhU39.png)

Like you can see, the title displays but not the text. I should add that I have tried all kinds of solutions, for intance resizing the box, changing font color (nothing happens), background color (the background color still remains) and using other text parameters such as setInformativeText, setDetailedText with the same result.

Does anyone know how to solve this mystery?

Comment: Since you ask a question with your message box, why not simply use the [`static` member function `question`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#question) to display the message box? No need to create your own instance of it.

Comment: I have tried that one too. Same result - the text does not display...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem recently, it turned out that my setText text was the same colour as my background. I changed the colour of the backround in my stylesheet and my setText appeared! 
In my stylesheet of the parent widget:

```
QDialogBox{
background-color: darkgray;
}
```

This is not a definitive solution, but I hope it can help someone out eventually.

Comment: This is not a qualified answer, It should be in comments.